# Executing SQL functions

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql

I'm not a programmer, so I need assistance with executing a SQL function in SQL Server 2000.

We have outsourced some work for an iPhone app which uses a web services located where I am. Everything is set-up correctly, but the outsourcing company has asked me to execute an SQL function on the database. I have no idea where to start with this.

This is the email they sent me, I received a txt file with the function in it:

1) Please execute SQL functions in your database that is written in the attached document i.e UDF.txt.

2) Some parameters are added in query string , these are accessed as a parameter in SQL query.

```
("ShowWhat")   = To switch between two SQL query
("latitude")   = Latitude
("longitude")  = Longitude
("distance")    = Distance of KM in which nearby ATM located.
("page")       = For which page records user want to see. (Ex: Page 1)
("strPageSize")= Results will be displayed as per size limit parameter for records.
```

Comment: Shouldn't the people you outsourced to provide information on how to access the database?

Comment: why not ask the outsourced company to help you with this?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need to run a script against your SQL Server 2000 database.

Find and execute the shortcut for SQL Query Analyzer whereever the SQL Server tools are installed. Likely they're installed on the server loaded with SQL Server 2000.

- Connect to the database instance. It could be an IP address or host name. i.e. "localhost"
- Change the database using the dropdown in the toolbar. The screenshot below shows master. Change it to whatever target database you want this function created in.
  *Open the script your vendor has supplied you by 'opening' the file/script. Alternatively you could copy/paste in the text into a new Query window.
- Press F5 to run the script, or click the green triangle in the toolbar.
- whatever SQL statements are in the file will be executed. Perhaps it's 1 or more CREATE or ALTER statements.

[image]

Comment: If you can't find the SQL Query Analyzer in your start menu, try running "isqlw" from the Start->Run dialog.

Comment: exactly what I needed. I thought it was along these lines but I was not game enought to try. Thankyou very much!